# React-Router not render IndexRoute not include AppRoute?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When use react-router, I got some problem, My router not render Layout component,Only render Index component,What's wrong with this?

My source code like this:

Router :

```
<Router history={createHistory queryKey: false} onUpdate={-> window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
<Route path="/" handler={Layout}>
  <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
  <Route path="movies" handler={Movies}>
    <Route path=":id" handler={Movies} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="books" handler={Books}>
    <Route path=":id" handler={Books} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Layout :

```
React = require "react"
{Router} = require "react-router"
{AppCanvas, AppBar} = require("material-ui")
require "./layout.less"
Layout = React.createClass
  render: ->
    <AppCanvas>
      <AppBar title="Title" iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more" />
      <div class="content">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    </AppCanvas>
module.exports = Layout
```

Index :

```
React = require "react"
Index = React.createClass
  render: ->
    <h1>Welcome,Home</h1>
module.exports = Index
```

Comment: github： https://github.com/Dreampie/reactjs-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've mixed `handler` and `component` attributes on your routes. `handler` was removed in the latest version of React Router.

Try:

```
<Router history={createHistory queryKey: false} onUpdate={-> window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
  <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
    <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
    <Route path="movies" component={Movies}>
      <Route path=":id" component={Movies} />
    </Route>
      <Route path="books" component={Books}>
      <Route path=":id" component={Books} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```